# How to get custom option value and title from ids in magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-options

How to get product custom option value and title from ids, I have following ids

```
[0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [option_id] => 3283
            [option_value] => 8893
        )
```

i want to get title of option_id(id) and value of option_value(id)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the option details from Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Configuration.

By default, you will get title values under getCustomOptions(). Instead of getting direct options details, you can pass the product with selected customOptions Items, so you can easily get the title.

```
public function getCustomOptions(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Configuration\Item\ItemInterface $item) {
    $product = $item->getProduct();
    $options = [];
    $optionIds = $item->getOptionByCode('option_ids');
    if ($optionIds) {
        $options = [];
        foreach (explode(',', $optionIds->getValue()) as $optionId) {
            $option = $product->getOptionById($optionId);
            if ($option) {
                $itemOption = $item->getOptionByCode('option_' . $option->getId());
                /** @var $group \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Type\DefaultType */
                $group = $option->groupFactory($option->getType())
                    ->setOption($option)
                    ->setConfigurationItem($item)
                    ->setConfigurationItemOption($itemOption);

                if ('file' == $option->getType()) {
                    $downloadParams = $item->getFileDownloadParams();
                    if ($downloadParams) {
                        $url = $downloadParams->getUrl();
                        if ($url) {
                            $group->setCustomOptionDownloadUrl($url);
                        }
                        $urlParams = $downloadParams->getUrlParams();
                        if ($urlParams) {
                            $group->setCustomOptionUrlParams($urlParams);
                        }
                    }
                }
                $options[] = [
                    'label' => $option->getTitle(),
                    'value' => $group->getFormattedOptionValue($itemOption->getValue()),
                    'option_id' => $option->getId(),
                    'option_type' => $option->getType(),
                    'option_type_id' => $itemOption->getValue(),
                    'custom_view' => $group->isCustomizedView(),
                ];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public function __construct(,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\ProductFactory $productFactory
) {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
}

$poductReource=$this->productFactory->create();
$attribute = $poductReource->getAttribute($attributeCode);
if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
    return  $option_Text = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($optionId);
}
```